# Eloquent: check if date is in between start and stop date

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an events table with 4 events all with different start and enddate.

```
mysql> select id, event_name, event_startdate, event_closedate from events;
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| id | event_name   | event_startdate     | event_closedate           |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|  1 | Event 1      | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |
|  2 | Event 2      | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       |
|  3 | Event 3      | 2016-07-01 00:00:00 | 2016-08-30 00:00:00       |
|  4 | Event 4      | 2016-09-01 00:00:00 | 2016-10-30 00:00:00       |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

I want to return the current events. In MySQL, the below query works:

```
mysql> select id, event_name, event_startdate, event_closedate from events where now() >= event_startdate and now() <= event_closedate;
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| id | event_name   | event_startdate     | event_closedate           |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|  1 | Event 1      | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |
|  2 | Event 2      | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

Now, I want to create the Eloquent equivalent. I have created the following:

```
$current_events = DB::table('events')->select('id','event_name', 'event_startdate', 'event_closedate')->where(DB::raw('now()'), '>=', 'event_startdate')->where(DB::raw('now()'), '<=', 'event_closedate')->get();
```

When I do a 'dd' output in Laravel, I get:

```
"select `id`, `event_name`, `event_startdate`, `event_closedate` from `events` where now() >= ? and now() <= ?"
```

The above is pretty similar to the query in MySQL that returns the two current events, so I was expecting to see the two events in my view but nothing is being output so I suspect I'm doing something wrong

The view is:

```
@foreach( $current_events as $event )
 <tr>
   <td align="center" class="hidden-xs">{{ $event->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $event->event_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $event->event_startdate }}</td>
   <td>{{ $event->event_closedate) }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Any reason why this does not return the two current events?

Comment: The two queries are exactly the same as far as I can see. Why don't you `dd($current_events)` and see what you get. Perhaps the code in your view is the problem, not the query.

Comment: I did a dd($current_events), it's in the original question. Both are the same indeed.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm not telling you to dump the query, i.e. `->toSql`. I'm telling you to dump the value of the query, i.e. `->get()`

Comment: Tried that indeed, but got nothing returned (no array). In the meantime I added the solution below. Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
$current_events = DB::table('events')->select( 'id','event_name', 'event_startdate', 'event_closedate' )
    ->where( DB::raw('now()'), '>=', DB::raw('event_startdate') )
    ->where( DB::raw('now()'), '<=', DB::raw('event_closedate') )->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. The DB:raw for the date columns did indeed the trick. I believe this is strange behaviour, but it works. I added the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if you use [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#query-scopes) inside your eloquent model, scopes makes your code easier to understand and works better than raw queries in your case. For example, in your model you should do:

```
class Event extends Model
{

    ...

    public function scopeCurrent($query)
    {
        return $query->where('event_startdate', '<=', Carbon\Carbon::now())
            ->where('event_closedate', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now());
    }

    ...

}
```

And anywhere in your controller:

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $todayEvents = Event::current()->select('id', 'event_name',  'event_startdate', 'event_closedate')->get();

        ...
    }
}
```

If you're having issues with Carbon, check the [docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly have a look. So Event::current() maps automatically to scopeCurrent() in the model, is that right?

Comment: You're right, scopes are pre-defined query conditions for filtering a model. You can also define dynamic scopes, take a look [here](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/06/23/using-scopes-with-laravel-5/).

Answer (score 0):

The correct query to use is:

```
$current_events = DB::table('events')->select( 'id','event_name', 'event_startdate', 'event_closedate' )
    ->where( DB::raw('now()'), '>=', DB::raw('event_startdate') )
    ->where( DB::raw('now()'), '<=', DB::raw('event_closedate') )->get();
```

instead of

```
$current_events = DB::table('events')->select('id','event_name', 'event_startdate', 'event_closedate')
    ->where(DB::raw('now()'), '>=', 'event_startdate')
    ->where(DB::raw('now()'), '<=', 'event_closedate')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Laravel uses Carbon dates.. this is a better solution. It also uses Eloquent models, rather than the DB class.

```
$current_event = Events::select( 'id','event_name', 'event_startdate', 'event_closedate' )
->where('event_startdate', '<=', Carbon::now())
->where('event_closedate', '>=', Carbon::now())->get();
```